# How to loop through Java arraylist entries by setting pager?

Tags: java, arraylist, size, pager

I have a requirement like need to loop through all entries of the web service by setting the pager with the initial size of 500. To achieve this I am writing a code which will get the initial 500 entries first time with pageindex 1 and then by increasing index to 2 and so on till all the entries i get. I have currently 504 entries to loop through. But I am getting the 1004 count from my code. Can anyone help me resolving this issue. Here is the code.

```
int pageIndex = 1;
            List<User> usersList = getUsers(pageIndex);
            List<User> allUsersList = new ArrayList<User>();
            allUsersList.addAll(usersList);
            while (!allUsersList.isEmpty()) {
                allUsersList = new ArrayList<User>();
                allUsersList = getUsers(pageIndex);
                usersList.addAll(allUsersList);
                pageIndex++;
            }
```

getUsers method is below:

```
private List<User> getUsers(int pageIndex){
UserFilter filter = new UserFilter();
    FilterPager pager = new FilterPager();
    pager.pageIndex = pageIndex;
    pager.pageSize = 500;
UserService userService = client.getUserService();
    return userService.list(filter, pager).objects;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same index twice. You don't need to handle the first index separate before you loop through the list.

Beside that, I think you could write your code shorter, for example like this:

```
int pageIndex = 1;
List<User> usersList;
List<User> allUsersList = new ArrayList<User>();
while ((usersList = getUsers(pageIndex++)) != null) {
    allUsersList.addAll(usersList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try on this.

Comment: I tried this too but getting some problem. So gone with other approach. Thank you so much for guiding me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite your while loop as follows :

```
int pageIndex = 1;
List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();

while (1 == 1) {
  allUsersList = getUsers(pageIndex);
  if (allUserList == null || allUserList.size() == 0)
    break;
  usersList.addAll(allUsersList);
  pageIndex++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this approach.